# How to solve flutter error String is not a subtype of type int

Tags: string, flutter, dart, int

I'm trying to learn flutter to develope mobile apps. And over github I have download a sample project for login system. Here it is;

https://github.com/vemarav/auth_flow

In this sample I have changed the api and endpoint with my api and Im getting this response;

```
{status: 1, message: User login successfully, data: {user_id: 3, name: user_name, email_id: user@email.com, password: *****, image: http://image.url, address: New York, office_address: Charleston & Huff, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA, live_lat: 41.2695887, live_long: -73.0302559, role: 2, status: 1, approval_status: 1, created_at: 1545317082, mobile: 0905375933055, referral_code: CKM676, user_referral_code: , gender: 1, city: new york, country: usa, updated_at: 1545317082, device_type: device_type, device_id: device_id, device_token: device_token, latitude: 37.4207325, longitude: -122.08313869999999, i_card: http://image.url, country_code: , mobile_no: , bank_name: , account_no: , ifsc_code: , account_holder_name: }}
```

But after response in auth_utils.dart page I have modified it to my requirements. After making this changes it's look like this.

```
var user = response['user'];
prefs.setInt(userIdKey, user['user_id']);
prefs.setString(nameKey, user['name']);
```

After these changes I get this error;

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'.
```

Maybe it's very easy but I'm new in flutter/dart and it's little bit complicated for me.

I have tried to convert the response to int ( maybe it's string ) but after that I get this error;

```
The method 'setInt' was called on null
```

Thanks for the response

---------------Edit---------------

I have checked the response from two api's and there is a difference between my response and the source in github. The code on github response is **int** and my response in **string**. That's why I have try to parse it with;

`prefs.setInt(userIdKey, int.parse(user['user_id']));`

After these code I get these error

`Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setInt' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: setInt("user_id", 3)`

But it's **not null**

And now i have test the `prefs.setString(nameKy, user['name'])` and this is given the same error. But it's **not null** too.

Comment: are you sure about response['user']  ? i mean var user =response['data'] works or not?

Comment: yes I'm sure. When I test it : `print(user['user_id'])` there is no problem. But in `prefs.setInt` it's give me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be entering null in `setInt`, handle before calling this method.

try it

```
prefs.setInt('userIdKey', user['user_id'] != null ? user['user_id'] : 0);
```

Or

```
    prefs.setInt('userIdKey', user['user_id'] ?? 0);
```

Comment: first off all thanks for your replay. But these data is not null.

Comment: `print(user['user_id']  != null ? user['user_id'] : 0);` these code print all time the right response.

Comment: Hi there,

first off all thanks for the response. i have found my mistake. I have forget to initialise it.

So that's why I have add a code for it and now it's works fine.